# Why do I have a never-ending do-while loop?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have a non-working `do-while` loop.  When I enter a *String* instead of an *int*, it should say "bla" and ask again to insert a number, but instead it sends the message text over and over again. What's wrong in this code?

```
    boolean i = true;
    do {
       i = false;  

       try {
           System.out.println("insert number");
           int k = sc.nextInt();  
       }
       catch(InputMismatchException e) {
           System.out.println("test");
           i = true;
       } 
   } while ( i== true);
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html: `When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.`. So, you need to skip the token once you get an `InputMismatchException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do `sc.nextLine()` in the `catch` block to clear the erroneous input. The [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29) call will leave the input in the buffer if it does not match the int pattern.

Comment: that really helped :D thank you a lot! that was a tricky one.

Comment: tip: *i* is already a boolean, so you dont need (i == true). Instead use while(i).